# Getting typeError: (options.astTransformers || []).map is not a function while running the test suite in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am getting below error while running jest test cases in Angular. All test suites are failing with this error.

Getting `typeError: (options.astTransformers || []).map is not a function` while running the test suite in Angular

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. What is the type of options.astTransformers? I suppose it's an array.

Comment: You made a mistake in configuration. See https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/215

Answer (score 3):

This solution is for Angular 8/9/10

I would recommend doing these steps:

1. Uninstall jest-preset-angular
2. Reinstall jest-preset-angular
3. Clear jest cache
4. Retry

If the above solution not working, try installing

```
npm install --dev ts-jest
```

Comment: Works fine to me. I got the problem after run "npm audit fix". With npm install --dev ts-jest command everything works normal.

Answer (score 3):

Fix this error by removing the following line in the jest.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    passWithNoTests: true,
    projects: '<rootDir>/libs/now-version' // <--- newly added property. should be removed
};
```

As I found this link on github.
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3885#issuecomment-706620382

This error started after updating Angular to 11, and when I generate a new lib inside NX and it ends up adding this new line, whenever a new lib is generated, by the CLI

Comment: Hi, can you translate your answer in english, such as Stackoverflow is an english website ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I ended up responding to the rush when I fixed the error, which I forgot to translate.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a newer version of the package.

In the `package.json` I changed the `jest-preset-angular` from `"8.3.2"` to `"8.2.0"` and that error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the **jest.config.js** as below fixed my issue

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'AppName',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
    },
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/appName',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
  testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2'
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Jest configuration for Angular can be tricky.

I recommend you use [jest-preset-angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular) which is a library that you will import into your Angular project that will manage the configuration of Jest for Angular.

This may be related to the update of Jest 27 that deprecated `astTransformers as string[]`.

Configure your Angular project to use Jest 26 with jest-preset-angular and you should be fine